# Hysteresis loop of a balloon

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain

According to [this website explaining the science behind balloons made of latex rubber](https://www.mwmresearchgroup.org/the-science-of-balloons-part-2.html),

> If we repeatedly load and unload (stretch and release) a viscoelastic
> material the amount of energy lost in the hysteresis loop will
> decrease with each cycle, until an equilibrium is reached.
> The force needed to achieve a certain deformation is less with each
> loading cycle, until we reach equilibrium.  This means that when we
> stretch the material, each subsequent stretch becomes easier.  This is
> known as preconditioning.  Repeatedly stretching a balloon
> preconditions the rubber, making it easier to inflate.

My question is why the hysteresis loop will decrease each time we stretch and release? Is it related to stress relaxation in which elastic strain is converted to plastic strain and therefore, lesser force is needed to stretch the balloon?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article [Natural rubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_rubber), rubber undergoes [Strain Crystallization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_crystallization). This has important effects on its fatigue properties. But the article doesn't into much detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it related to stress relaxation in which elastic strain is converted to plastic strain

Yes, it is as simple as this. Party balloons are made from natural latex and this is a complex mixture of many chemicals. The dried latex is somewhere in between a solid and a liquid. It doesn't flow like a liquid, but the polymers in it have considerable freedom to adjust their conformation so there is some internal motion that is similar to a *flow* of a very thick liquid. The flow is slow so it does not reach equilibrium in a single stretch, and that's why you see a change between repeated stretches.